# Was this character in Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

While watching the credits for *Avengers: Endgame*, I noticed

> that Sean Gunn was credited as both the on-set Rocket and as Kraglin Obfonteri.

However, I don't remember seeing the latter in the film. The Marvel Cinematic Universe wiki also says that he's in the movie. Did I miss something? I know there isn't much to this question, but I'm just wondering.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [Screen Rant](https://screenrant.com/avengers-endgame-every-character-spoiler/), he was in the final battle:

> **Kraglin** - As one of the few remaining Ravagers, Kraglin joined the fight alongside the Guardians of the Galaxy to defeat the Mad Titan and his galaxy-destroying army once and for all.

Comment: And immediately shot himself in the foot with Yondu’s dart.